# Detecting change in appended form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

When the `load_upload()` function gets executed, I want an explorer window to automatically open, so the user can select a file (`$(imageFileInput).click();`), and when a file is selected, I want the form to submit automatically.

The problem is that, when the form is generated dynamically as seen below, changes are somehow not detected. This seems to make it impossible to automatically submit the form when the value of imageFile changes.

How could I automatically submit the form this way? Any help is much appreciated!

```
function load_upload() {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "image_upload_process.php";
    form.id = 'imageForm';

    var imageFileInput = document.createElement('input');
    imageFileInput.type = "file";
    imageFileInput.id = 'imageFile';
    $(imageFileInput).click();
    form.appendChild(imageFileInput);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
};
```

My change event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    document.getElementById("imageFile").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("imageForm").submit();
    };
});
```

Comment: You are clicking it before you add it to the page?

Comment: @epascarello Yes but the file window still opens.

Comment: You do not show your change event.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I've added that now.

Comment: Maybe this?: $("#imageFile").change(function(){$("#imageForm").submit()});

Comment: You are adding the event to the element before it exists, it does not magically get hooked up

Comment: event delegation: `$(document).on("change", "#imageFile", function() {} );` or bind it when you create the element.

Comment: @epascarello How stupid of me, of course! Thank you very much, that did the trick indeed. Many thanks! :-)